# Build in admin accounts get disable after sysprep

Tags: azure

i have created one windows machine in my hyper-v after sysprep i have upload my VHD to azure account

when i am trying to login that windows machine i am unable to login the account getting disable

can any one please let me know how to login into that machine in azure account

In Adv Thanks.

Comment: Do you try to reset password for your VM on Azure Portal? You could create a new user.

Comment: Thank you so much walter
i don't want to reset my password without that i need to login
for windows server machine i am able to login but i am facing problem with windows 10

Comment: I suggest you could rest password to logon your VM and enable your admin accounts.

Comment: ya walter i know this method but my problem is i have so many machines 
for each machine i can't disable can you please let me know why this is happening for windows10 but i am not facing problem with server machine

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is disabled.

`sysprep` is designed to put the OS into OEM state. All local accounts and user profiles are deleted. Because it will be the base image for all your future VMs. 
This process creates a so called `generalized image`. The process is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sa-copy-generalized). You can read more about `sysprep` itself and the process of generalization [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721940%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

What you probably need (only probably, because you do not state your real use case), is a `specialized image`. `Specialized image` is the only way to just use the VM as is - with all its user profiles. You can read about that process [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/create-vm-specialized).

By using the `specialized image` your OS is left untouched with all its user profiles.